# Perl: Hash slices cannot be lexically scoped

Tags: perl, hash, scope, slice, variable-declaration

I have really no idea, why this is wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.20;
package MyDate;
sub new{ bless {}, shift; }
sub AUTOLOAD{
    my $f = our $AUTOLOAD;
    my @h{qw[Wday Month Year]} = (localtime)[3,4,5];
}
```

Err:compilation error near `"@h{"`

---

If I delete `my` (or even if package-scoped with `our`):

```
@h{qw[Wday Month Year]} = (localtime)[3,4,5];
```

It will magically works. Why cannot be hash slices lexically scoped?

Edit: Yes - I have not noticed, that `(localtime)[3] = mday` not wday. But that is not the point. I am asking about the scope, not localtime func.

Edit2: The hash `%h` (the point of my question), is intended to be used inside the `autoload` sub (well, of course when I am trying to use it as hash slice there). Just for clarity.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `my` declares a variable in that lexical scope (which is the `{}` visible surrounding it, or the file it's in otherwise). It cannot declare an arbitrary expression like a hash slice - you need to declare the hash in the appropriate scope first, and then apply a hash slice to it.

Comment: thanks, why is needed, to have declared hash first? And - more importantly - in what block, should it be that is - only one block outside ? - in my case in block of package, or even more 'outside' (so it become variable of package Main). What is the right depth, of lexical scope

Comment: It's needed for the same reason you need to declare a hash before assigning to one of its keys, you need to declare lexical variables to create them and then you can use components of them afterward. The correct scope is the smallest scope that still contains everywhere the variable is needed.

Comment: Wday should be Mday; Wday is at index 6 and unlikely to be what you want anyway

Comment: There are two primary reasons for declaring lexical variables. The first is so that you can use `strict` to help you avoid common misspelling or scoping mistakes. The second is to indicate to Perl what the enclosing scope should be for the lexical variable you are declaring. You may be able to perfectly avoid miispellings and scoping oversights (though try as I might, I cannot), but Perl could not guess what scope you want the variable constrained to. And without that, everything is global.

Comment: @DavidO but what about not using strict, yet using properly `my` (at least try to). I know, that you can still make scope mistakes, however you will have more freedom, especially in situations like this one.

Comment: @Herdsman Always use strict. The only freedom you gain by not using strict is the freedom to make more mistakes. It does not help in this situation.

Comment: @Herdsman, if you need to disable a specific aspect of strict in a small part of code, you can do so.  Your default should be to have it turned up to 11, and then when you need to do something strict dislikes (use a symbolic reference to inject a subroutine with it's name in a variable, for example).  strict is your friend.  https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/strict.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@h{...}` is not a variable, so you can't declare it as such.

`@h{...} = ...;` sets elements of `%h`. So it's `%h` you need to create.

This is done as follows:

```
my %h;
```

---

By the way, I doubt you have a legitimate reason for using `AUTOLOAD`. Keep in mind that code at the top level (at the file level) of a module will be executed when the module is first loaded in an interpreter.

Comment: I do not understand `top level` neither `file level`, are you trying to say, to rather use regular subrutines, then load them from `autoload` afterwards?

Comment: `package Foo; use strict; use warnings; sub foo { ... } insert_code_to_run_on_load_here; 1`

Answer (score 1):

I hope that you will see your mistakes from following piece of code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use v5.20;

package MyDate;

sub new{ bless {}, shift; }

sub AUTOLOAD{
    my $f = our $AUTOLOAD;
    #my %h;               # !!! without hash declaration compilation error
    #     0    1    2     3     4    5     6     7     8
    #my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =
    #                                            localtime(time);
    @h{qw[Wday Month Year]} = (localtime)[6,4,5];
}
```

perl hash_package.pl

```
Global symbol "%h" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %h"?) at hash_package.pl line 15.
Execution of hash_package.pl aborted due to compilation errors (#1)
    (F) You've said "use strict" or "use strict vars", which indicates
    that all variables must either be lexically scoped (using "my" or "state"),
    declared beforehand using "our", or explicitly qualified to say
    which package the global variable is in (using "::").

Uncaught exception from user code:
        Global symbol "%h" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %h"?) at hash_package.pl line 15.
        Execution of hash_package.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Can you explain your code? Also, I don't think the different array indexes on the return value from `localtime` are the problem. (The array indexes,  the `uses strict; use warnings;`, and white spacing seems to be the only difference between your code and the question's code). But the OP asked about a compilation time error.

Comment: @Rober -- coder can not initialize _slice of the hash_ at it's declaration! The hash should be declared `my %h;` and only after that it can be initialized. `use strict; use warnings;` often help to find abnormalities in code which potentially lead to errors. OP tried to save in `$h[Wday] = $mday`.

Comment: (Please [edit] your answer instead of adding comments; comments may or may not be shown.) I agree on the `use strict; use warnings;`, but they don't make a difference for me when I try to run the OP's code. He already mentioned that it works when he removed `my`. So I don't see what your answer adds, especially cause the question was about a *compiler error*, not about getting the wrong week day from `localtime`. That was my question.

Comment: @Robert -- although `use strict; use warnings;` did not change much in this case but it is a good practice. `use diagnostics;` does code compilation more descriptive on an errors.

Comment: @PolarBear - also - why would you declare the hash `%h` in sub block, and not to upper block - package's block? I thought, once the sub is done, no data on stack will remain, but maybe, I do not even need the hash after that anymore, so it doesn't matter really.

Comment: @Herdsma -- well this question should be directed to OP. I just indicated what caused compilation error -- from original post is not clear how hash will be used, inside **AUTOLOAD** sub or on **package** level.

Comment: @PolarBear I admit, I haven't mentioned, I will edit. Hash Will be used inside `autoload`. Anyway still is not answer to scoping problem.

Comment: @Herdsman `my %h; @h{qw[Wday Month Year]} = (localtime)[6,4,5];` is not what you desire? Otherwise I do not understand your question. What variable scope are you looking for %h hash?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a big WAG at what the OP is trying to do.  So it's a pretty crappy SO answer according to site conventions, but I think it might help unmuddy the waters for our suffering OP.

I'm going to start with the code the OP posted, comment a bit on it, and then move to several examples of the "right way to do it".

OP's code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

So we're running a script.

```
use v5.20;
```

With version 5.20 or better. So far, so good.

```
package MyDate;
```

Now we've selected a new namespace/package called `MyDate`.  While this isn't illegal, it is generally considered desirable to have one package per file.

```
sub new{ bless {}, shift; }
```

We have a constructor.  So `MyDate` is going to be a class.  Maybe worth looking at Moose or Moo for help with automating some of the boring crap with class construction.  But there isn't anything wrong with using good, ole' classical Perl objects.

```
sub AUTOLOAD{
    my $f = our $AUTOLOAD;
    my @h{qw[Wday Month Year]} = (localtime)[3,4,5];
}
```

The syntax error, the source of all pain.  `AUTOLOAD` is called to handle any unknown function calls in the namespace.  So, this in-effect, intercepts all undefined method calls.  MyDate has an infinite list of methods.  It's probably not what is really needed.

Let's rework things a bit:

Here's my guess at the sort of thing the OP may want in their script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.20;
use strict;    # Make life easier by catching bugs at compile time.
use warnings;  # Catch things that probably indicate errors, but aren't technically illegal.

use MyDate;    # Load my date class

# Make some dates
my $today = MyDate->new();
my $aprilish = MyDate->new( month => 4 );

# Do stuff with them!
print_date( $today );
print_date( $aprilish );

sub print_date {
    my ($date) = @_;

    say "Weekday: ", $date->wday();
    say "Month: ", $date->month();
    say "Year: ", $date->year();
}
```

Library File:  MyDate.pm

```
package MyDate;

use v5.20;     # Set the minimum perl version required. Optional, but useful.
use strict;    # Always
use warnings;

sub new {
    my ($class, %parts) = @_;

    my %defaults; @defaults[wday month year] = localtime(3, 4, 5)
    my $self = bless {
        %defaults,
    }, $class;

    for my $part ( qw/ month wday year /) {
        next unless exists $parts{$part};

        $self->$part( $parts{$part} );  # Call the associated method to initialize an attribute.
        delete $parts{$part};
    }

    die "Unknown attributes: ", join ', ', keys %parts  # Fatal error on unknown args
        if %parts;

    return $self;
}

# The other methods are mostly identical.
sub month {
    my ($self, $value) = @_;

    if ( @_ == 2 ) {  # If two args are passed, we are a setter.
        $self->{month} = $value;
    }

    return $self->{month};
}
```

That's a classical perl OO version of something like the OP is going for, I think.

It's a lot less hassle to write with [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo).

```
package MyDate;

use v5.20;     # Set the minimum perl version required. Optional, but useful.
use Moo;       # Turns on strict and warnings;
use namespace::autoclean;  # Removes any utility functions so they don't show up as methods.    

has 'month' => (
  is => 'ro',
  builder => 1,
);

has 'wday' => (
  is => 'ro',
  builder => 1,
);

has 'year' => (
  is => 'ro',
  builder => 1,
);

sub _build_month { localtime()[4] }
sub _build_wday { localtime()[3] }
sub _build_year { localtime()[5] }
```

But probably the best thing to do would be to take an existing date manipulation library like [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) and use it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.20;
use strict;    # Make life easier by catching bugs at compile time.
use warnings;  # Catch things that probably indicate errors, but aren't technically illegal.

use DateTime;    # Load my date class

# Make some dates
my $today = DateTime->today();
my $aprilish = DateTime->today()->set_month( 4 );

# Do stuff with them!
print_date( $today );
print_date( $aprilish );

sub print_date {
    my ($date) = @_;

    say "Weekday: ", $date->day_of_week();
    say "Month: ", $date->month();
    say "Year: ", $date->year();
}
```

Anyhow, I hope that all this is useful to the OP, and maybe, just maybe, to someone else.